# Bash 4.2 on Windows without virtual machine?

Tags: windows, bash, cross-platform

I'm looking for the way to run bash 4.2 on Windows without a virtual machine.

I've tried with CygWin, but the latest version that you can install is bash 4.1, and I didn't find a way to install bash 4.2 on CygWin.

[Here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2011-02/msg00027.html) the developer told that he was porting bash 4.2 to CygWin, but it has been written two years ago.

Other software like `win-bash` or `MinGW` have older versions of bash.

So, is there any way to install bash 4.2 on Windows?

Comment: This question would be more suitable to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Because Cygwin doesn't hold the version you want I think your only option is to compile 4.2 yourself and then install it.

I don't know how convienent that would be for you however.

The bash source code is available here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/

You can find details here about compiling and installing it: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Installing-Bash   From a very brief inspection it looks as though you would need to install cygwin first and compile it from there.

These instructions for installing bash from 'linux from scratch' may be of some use to you: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/bash.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply but I tried it and it didn't work.
You can see the updated info here:
http://superuser.com/questions/684155/bash-4-2-on-windows-without-virtual-machine